# Print a specific part of output of a command

Tags: command-line

So, here I have a simple commmand:

```
xset -q | grep -e Num -e Caps
```

The output of the command is:

```
00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
```

What I want to know is that, are there any possibilities of printing only the on and off parts, such as,

- print only `off` after `Caps Lock`
- print only `on` after `Num Lock`

E.g., if I need to get the status of Caps Lock, I need to run the command such that the output is only

`off` or `on`

Comment: What's the output you're looking for? Given an example.

Comment: @muru - added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
% xset -q | grep -Eo '(Caps Lock|Num Lock):[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+'
Caps Lock:   off
Num Lock:    on
```

- `(Caps Lock|Num Lock)` matches either `Caps Lock` or `Num Lock`
- the above will be followed by `:` and then character class `[[:blank:]]` matches one or more space or tab
- Them `[^[:blank:]]+` will match one or more characters prior to next space or tab i.e. `on` or `off`.

Comment: @heemyl - thank you so much! That worked as expected but could you please explain the command a little as I am a newbie here, I shall be greatly obliged.

Comment: @Raphael Please check  my edits

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWK as well. It allows printing columns (which are by default assumed to be space separated)

```
xieerqi:$ xset -q | awk '/Caps/'                                                                      
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
xieerqi:$ xset -q | awk '/Caps Lock/ {print $4" "$8}'                                                 
off off
```

Comment: What does `{print $4" "$8}` do?

Comment: @Raphael it tells awk to print column 4 and column 8. The " " tells to just put space in between

Comment: note the space is the default separator, so saying `print $1 " " $2` is exactly the same as `print $1, $2`.

Comment: @fedorqui thank you , noted. Is this a `gawk` specific feature  or it is not limited to that ? Also, where in the man page can be found info on this ?

Comment: It is common in all awks. Check `OFS` in any `man`, for example http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/ --> `OFS    output field separator (default blank).

Comment: I did know about OFS, but I didn't know print can be used with items separated by commas. Thank you !

Comment: Yep! That's the beauty of OFS: it let's you define how the fields are separated and comes very handy on cases like this with `print`, making the code look cleaner.